# Cannot call a method which includes Thread.sleep method

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am implementing Thread.sleep() in a method and am trying to call this method from another class;however, every time I do this the code just freezes. I have got a feeling that it has something to do with the InterruptedException that Thread.sleep() causes.

Here is a sample:

**class name is A**

```
....
public static void start() throws InterruptedException
{
    //other code
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
...
```

**Separate class**

```
    ...
    public static void call()
    {
        new A().start();
    }
    ...
```

start() is in one class, call() is in a separate class, and call() is attempting to call the start method from the first class.

Comment: You are looping forever in a `while` loop, and you are asking why your code stops there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 every time I do this the screen just freezes
```

That is because `Thread.sleep(10);` in a `while loop` will put your current Thread to blocking state thus freezing your screen.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call the method, while-loop begins and it never stops because of its condition!

```
  while (true) {  <<<<<<<<<< change it to a logical condition or take it out
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not wisdom to use this condition which make this while loop never stop,
it's a dead loop, that's why it freezes.

```
while (true) {  
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
```